# Django Forms throwing ValueError

Tags: python, django

I have two functions: `create_questions` and `edit_questions`; however, the former throws an error stating `invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'create_question'` while the latter just works fine. I cannot understand why this is happening because they are basically the same function.

views.py

```
def question_detail(request, pk):
    question = get_object_or_404(models.Question, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'questions/question_detail.html', {
        'question': question,
    })


def create_question(request):
    form = QuestionForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = QuestionForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid:
            question = form.save(commit=False)
            question.author = request.user
            question.save()
            messages.success(request, "Question created successfully")
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('questions:question_detail', kwargs={'pk': question.pk}))
    return render(request, 'questions/question_form.html', {'form': form})

def edit_question(request, pk):
    question = get_object_or_404(models.Question, pk=pk)
    form_class = QuestionForm
    form = form_class(instance=question)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = form_class(request.POST, instance=question)
        if form.is_valid:
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, "Question updated successfully")
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('questions:question_detail', kwargs={'pk': question.pk}))
    return render(request, 'questions/question_form.html', {
        'form': form,
        'question': question
    })
```

forms.py

```
class QuestionForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = models.Question
        fields = [
            'title', 'body', 'tags'
        ]
```

models.py

```
class Question(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Postechian, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="", null=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tags(), blank=True)
    body = models.TextField(default='')
    rank = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-created_at", "-updated_at"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

urls.py

```
path('create_question/', views.create_question, name="create_question"),
    path('edit_question/<pk>', views.edit_question, name="edit_question"),
```

I would appreciate any help.

**EDIT**

I am posting the full traceback.

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/poverflow/create_question/

Django Version: 2.2.7
Python Version: 3.7.4
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'users.apps.UsersConfig',
 'tags.apps.TagsConfig',
 'poverflow.apps.PoverflowConfig']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/Users/jyoon/Documents/PoStack/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Users/jyoon/Documents/PoStack/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Users/jyoon/Documents/PoStack/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/jyoon/Documents/PoStack/poverflow/views.py" in question_detail
  19.     question = get_object_or_404(models.Question, pk=pk)

File "/Users/jyoon/Documents/PoStack/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py" in get_object_or_404
  93.         return queryset.get(*args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/jyoon/Documents/PoStack/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in get
  399.         clone = self.filter(*args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/jyoon/Documents/PoStack/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in filter
  892.         return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/jyoon/Documents/PoStack/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _filter_or_exclude
  910.             clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))

File "/Users/jyoon/Documents/PoStack/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in add_q
  1290.         clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)

File "/Users/jyoon/Documents/PoStack/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in _add_q
  1318.                     split_subq=split_subq, simple_col=simple_col,

File "/Users/jyoon/Documents/PoStack/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in build_filter
  1251.         condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)

File "/Users/jyoon/Documents/PoStack/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in build_lookup
  1116.         lookup = lookup_class(lhs, rhs)

File "/Users/jyoon/Documents/PoStack/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py" in __init__
  20.         self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()

File "/Users/jyoon/Documents/PoStack/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py" in get_prep_lookup
  70.             return self.lhs.output_field.get_prep_value(self.rhs)

File "/Users/jyoon/Documents/PoStack/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py" in get_prep_value
  972.         return int(value)

Exception Type: ValueError at /poverflow/create_question/
Exception Value: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'create_question'
```

Comment: Can you please share the *full traceback*?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I have added the full traceback.

Comment: Is your url by any change `edit_question/create_question` or `edit_question/edit_question`? It looks like you thus take that as primary key.

Comment: @jypoonPro: usually that happens if you *manually* write URLs in the templates, and thus the URL path "hierarchy" might work against you.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem no, my URL is `poverflow/create_question` and `poverflow/edit_question`. I am also seeing this error even if I remove all written URLs in the templates.

Comment: The error is not coming from either of these views, but from question_detail.

Comment: as pointed here `question = get_object_or_404(models.Question, pk=pk)`, can you edit your question with the *question_detail* view added?

Comment: Everything looks good! the problem may come from codes that are not shown here... the whole URL in *urls.py*, the templates related to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite frustrating; however, the error came from the URL having an extra `/` at the end: so `/create_question` works but `/create_question/` would throw an error.